# Bokeh one slider for hiding multiple renderers

Tags: python, bokeh

I am developing an application with Bokeh with multiple bar charts. Each chart has multiple renderers, one for each year of data, and all charts are embedded and run on Flask---code for one chart is shown below.

I want to add one slider that will show/hide bars corresponding to one or years of data but I could only find online how to make a slider change data shown by one renderer, not to completely get rid of it. I have tried both approaches shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50681244/bokeh-slider-stacked-bar-chart). They did not work because:

- I am using Flask rather than the Bokeh server (I am a high performance computing guy rather than web-anything, and Flask was already set up by someone else), and
- I cannot figure out the JS callback for multiple renderers.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

```py
import datetime

import pandas as pd

from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox, column
from bokeh.models import Slider, HoverTool
from bokeh.plotting import ColumnDataSource, figure, show
from bokeh.embed import components
from bokeh.transform import dodge
from bokeh import palettes

BAR_GROUP_WIDTH = 0.6
MONTHS = [
    'January', 
    'Febuary', 
    'March', 
    'April',
    'May',
    'June',
    'July',
    'August',
    'September',
    'October',
    'November',
    'December'
]

data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {'Month': ['January', 'Febuary', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
'2017': [11.6124, 7.11175, 9.366717, 11.071917, 4.849774, 10.0885, 14.81031, 15.486875, 14.877268, 14.025417, 11.203527, 11.09575],
'2018': [10.480874, 11.042208, 11.874903, 12.120542, 15.4275, 19.12525, 16.546917, 9.330083, 6.740833, 2.145, 5.919208, 15.946958],
'2019': [11.521308, 7.023, 9.282109, 10.518875, 12.664917, 9.953042, 13.494, 11.729083, 14.696792, 10.704042, 8.468698, 13.1605],
'2020': [11.162708, 7.276667, 15.194272, 16.654917, 19.552996, 20.480625, 14.800629, 7.722917, 19.260708, 18.052994, 17.488208, 19.442917],
'2021': [18.712944, 17.520792, 18.69113, 17.505542, 21.687413, 20.725637, 10.538542, 19.516708, 17.576167, 20.552875, 13.38375, 17.651667],
'2022': [17.027417, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
)

now = datetime.datetime.now()
years = [str(y) for y in range(2017, 2022)]
title = 'Test Plot'
source = ColumnDataSource(data=data)
p = figure(
    x_range=MONTHS, 
    y_range=(0, data[years].max().max() * 1.25), 
    height=350, width=900, 
    title=title.center(100)
)

renderers = []
for ix, y in enumerate(years):        
    # Here I generate one renderer for each group of twelve bars corresponding to all months in a year
    d = -BAR_GROUP_WIDTH / 2 + BAR_GROUP_WIDTH / (len(years) - 1) * ix
    r = p.vbar(x=dodge('Month', d, range=p.x_range), top=y, width=BAR_GROUP_WIDTH / len(years), 
        source=source, line_color="white", 
        color=palettes.Category10[len(years)][ix], 
        legend_label=y
    )
    tooltip = [
        ('YEAR', y),
        ('MONTH', '@Month'),
        ('TOTAL', f'@{y}')
    ]
    p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=tooltip, renderers=[r]))
    renderers.append(r)

p.x_range.range_padding = 0.1
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.legend.location = "top_left"
p.legend.orientation = "horizontal"

# How do I make this slider do what I want it to do?
slider = Slider(start=2017, end=now.year, value=now.year, step=1, title="Range")

layout = column(p, widgetbox(slider))
show(layout)

# # My application is running on Flask and I'm embedding Bokeh components, so I actually use components rather than show.
# script, div = components(layout)
# return (script, div)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is what you are looking for

[image: wanted output]

you can use that each of your renderers has an attribute `visible`. You can set this to `True` or `False`.

You have to import `CustomJS` and then write some JavaScript code and connect this through a callback to the slider.

```
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(renderers=p.renderers, year=2017), code="""
    const f = cb_obj.value;
    if(cb_obj.value == 2022){
        for(let r of renderers)
            r.visible = true
    }
    else{
        for(let r of renderers)
            r.visible = false
        renderers[f-year].visible = true
    }
""")
slider = Slider(start=2017, end=now.year, value=now.year, step=1, title="Range")
slider.js_on_change('value', callback)
```

In the implementation of this example, all renderers are set as visible if you select the year 2022, else only the renderer of the selected year is visible and all other are invisible.